# Logs overwritten in CruiseCControl.NET when there is multiple MSBuild Tasks

Tags: msbuild, logging, cruisecontrol.net

I have two MSBuild tasks in my CC.NET config. In the end of the execution, i can see two blocks of warnings/errors in the log and published email. But the problem is that the contents of both the blocks are the same and that is from the second MSBuild task!! In another way, the second MSBuild task overwrites the first log, and then creates another one for itself effectively creating two exactly identical block!!!
Do anybody have any thoughts on this? I am happy to provide more information if you require about the environment and configuration.

Thanks,
James Poulose

Answer (score 0):

1/ Do you have two msbuild tasks inside ccnet config file ?

2/ In the MSBuild task, try to add the msbuild logger

[path_to_ccnet]\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll